# What is the relationship between Document and Element? Why does a parent element also have getElementsByTagName method?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been really troubled in the relationship between `Document` and `Element` since I found that a `ul` element also can use `getElementsByTagName` method to get its descendants.

I can understand that the `document` object, as an instance of `Document`, has those methods that is inherited from `Document`. But I can't understand why an instance of `Element` also have those methods.

Where are those methods from? What is the relationship between `Document` and `Element`?

Comment: @jongo45 `element.querySelector(All)` is just cool! Regardless of old browsers(< IE8), there's no need to use selector library.

Comment: Sorry I removed the comment because I think I completely missed the question. I thought you were asking why it was needed and not what the relationship is.  I looked:  It turns out that both Document and Element inherit from Node, and both inherit querySelector and querySelectorAll from ParentNode, BUT neither inherit getElementsByTagName from anywhere, they're just functions of the same name defined on both Document and Element.  See [interface-document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) and [interface-element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element).

Comment: @jongo45 that's all right. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [`Document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) and [`Element.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) are different methods. But it makes sense for both Document and Element to have such a method: A document has "child" elements, and an element does, too.

To answer your broader question, [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) both inherit from [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) (as do DocumentFragment and a few other interfaces). Node defines a number of properties and methods common to Document and Element, such as `nodeType`, `childNodes`, and `appendChild()`. As MDN notes, "These interfaces may return null in particular cases where the methods and properties are not relevant," so e.g. `document.parentNode` returns `null`. But as it turns out, your example `getElementsByTagName` isn't defined by Node—it's defined separately by Document and Element.

For understanding the DOM, MDN (where all of the above links lead) is your best friend. It'll tell you not only what each property and method is for, but also what interface it's defined in.

Comment: Thanks! I just found `Document.prototype` and `Element.prototype` both have `getElementsByTagName`! The links in your answer are really helpful. :)